# PHP strftime("%z", time()) for the Europe/Moscow zoneinfo file is giving wrong GMT offset

Tags: php, timezone

Yes, I have the latest Time Zone data. Got it from a centos rpm for 2015b timezone data.  It does have the 2014 change in it as you can see below.
(I have also compiled the zone files from IANA for 2015b with same result)

Yes, my php.ini and phpcli.ini files have `date.timezone = Europe/Moscow`

Using `PHP 5.5.10, Httpd: 2.4.9`.

But when I get the time zone it is off by 1 hour.

```
<?php
$zoneFormat = "%z";
$localtime = strftime($zoneFormat, time());
echo "localtime=".$localtime . "\n";
```

Give output of:

```
[root@cougar ~]# php qtime.php
localtime=+0400
```

But if I do the same with a samll c program:

```
[root@cougar ~]# cpptime
Result string is "2015 04 01 22:40:20 MSK:+0300"
```

And if I dump the array from a getTransitions() call it stops at 2011.

Anybody else ran into this with the Europe/Moscow zone info file from the 2015b in PHP.

```
Europe/Moscow  Sat Mar 26 22:59:59 2011 UTC = Sun Mar 27 01:59:59 2011 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800
Europe/Moscow  Sat Mar 26 23:00:00 2011 UTC = Sun Mar 27 03:00:00 2011 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=14400
Europe/Moscow  Sat Oct 25 21:59:59 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:59:59 2014 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=14400
Europe/Moscow  Sat Oct 25 22:00:00 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:00:00 2014 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800
Europe/Moscow  Mon Jan 18 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Mon Jan 18 06:14:07 2038 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800
Europe/Moscow  Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out there were 2 options to fix this. Since PHP has its own copy of the timezone files and does not use the time zone files of the system.

1) Upgrade PHP to a version that has the latest timezone database in it.

2) Or add the timezone extension to my php installation.  The time zone extensions can be found at https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb